# Remove a shortcut from Unity

Tags: unity, shortcuts

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and this strange shortcut in applications lens :

[image]

There's no such shortcut file in

`~/.local/share/applications/` nor in `/usr/share/applications`

I've cleared files and applications cache using `activity-log-manager`.

How can I remove it?

Comment: You installed dbvis so remove it, if installed from the .deb then `sudo apt-get purge dvbis`

Comment: Note that the *filename* of the .desktop file is not the name you see in Dash. In Dash, you see the name as in the line, starting with `Name=`, inside the `.desktop` file (or a localized additional  line).